# append string to textbox contents?

Tags: jquery, textbox, append

pretty simple, I have buttons but i want to add their value to a textbox when they are clicked, how would i go about doing this in jQuery? They are all numbers and their cant be more than 10 in the textbox.

Comment: did you try jquery .val()/// it should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jquery .val to set the text box value , it should do it

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 6):

pretty easy task with jQuerys `.val()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/width/)</sup> method:

```
$('button').click(function(event) {
    $('input:text').val(function(index, val) {
        return val + event.target.value;
    });
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/QFm7K/

Comment: the superscript link is cute :-)

Comment: I INVENTED IT! ME ME ITS MEEE *maybe **patrick dw** won't see this* :p

Comment: Hi how can I use this when I am having multiple textboxes, i need to append the text for focused control

Answer (score 2):

or

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('textarea')[0].value += $(this).val();
});
```